# Making my plugin create a page?

Tags: plugins, posts, pages, database

I have created a plugin that creates a table in the database and allows users to add an Item to the table. I would like each item to also create a page for its self so that when the items are listed I can have each one link to there individual pages. Anyone know the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to insert a physical page, though I would suggest creating one page for the plugin and then using a rewrite rule to give all of your items a URL with that single page as the base.

**EDIT**

quick rewrite example with added query var:

```
function wpa55546_rewrites(){
    $page_slug = 'your-page';

    // urls will be in the form
    // /your-page/42/

    add_rewrite_rule(
        $page_slug . '/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=' . $page_slug . '&my_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa55546_rewrites' );


function wpa55546_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'my_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa55546_query_vars' );
```

then in the template you'll have access to the value of your query var:

```
echo get_query_var( 'my_id' );
```

you'll also have to [flush rewrite rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) at the appropriate time.

Comment: could you give or link an example? Not sure what you mean about a "rewrite rule". You mean I create a page, then call the tables I want displayed on that page?

Comment: @KirillFuchs - see edit